# Make SQL Server 2012 Database in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio

I am new to visual studio and publishing my very first vb database application. The problem I have is when I run the program on a different computer the database doesn't connect due to different SQL Server  versions. I cannot install SQL Server 2016 on that pc as it is 32 bit.I have SQL SERVER LOCALDB 2014 on that but error database version is 852 and supported is 782....downgrade not possible

Comment: Install `Sql Server Management Studio` and then you can give that server reference in connection string. We can run same database on different version of `Sql Server`.

Comment: Thanks I will try that and inform